# How do you maximize a polynomial over an integer domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am working on maximizing the polynomial $f:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$f(v):=\prod_{i=1}^{N}( v_i+\alpha_i^2)$$ over integer $n$-partitions of $P$, $n\leq N$: $$\left\{v \left|\, v_i \in \{0,1,2,\dots, N\} \ ; \sum_i v_i = P \right. \right\}$$

This can be done by brute-force in application, but that seems very awful for even moderate $P, N$.

An implicit form for the continuous case is done in Lemma II of this paper: http://ee.ucd.ie/~mark/papers/ISSC_Water_Pouring.pdf

If you find the continuous solution and round it, the error will be less than I think $(0.5+A)^N$, $A$ being the largest of all the $\alpha^2$s corresponding to a nonzero weight. (Haven't looked very closely yet but this is what I got after some algebra). This is a very rough bound. Is it possible to get closer in general?

Can anyone suggest any reading   on the topic?

Comment: You're trying to maximise a product of $N$ non-negative terms with a constant sum. This happens when the terms are all equal in the continuous case, and "as close to each other as possible" in the integer case. So you look for those partitions which make $v_i+\alpha_i^2$ closest to each other.  Perhaps a greedy algorithm starting with the largest $\alpha_i$ term may work much better than brute force anyway.

Comment: Is there an obvious proof for the 'as close together as possible' statement? My rounding result got me scared that coarse inputs make error blow up.  (Objects like Wilkinson's polynomial might also be relevant)

Comment: That follows from convexity and smoothing. More precisely, it is an extension of $a>b \implies (a+1)(b-1)=ab-(a-b)-1<ab$. starting from any initial candidate partition, whether you can reach the global optimum by smoothing at each stage (moving terms on both sides closer to the middle) is not something I have tested.

Comment: How large problems are you targeting?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg In the order of $N=20$ if not larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N$ and $P$ are not too large, and @Macavity is correct about the solution minimizing the largest deviation of $v_i+\alpha_i^2$, the problem appears to be rather easily solved using mixed-integer linear programming. However, I do not always get the correct solution.

I've developed a test below in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me) using Gurobi to solve the MILPs.

To check if the solution is correct (for very small $N$), I use a much more expensive approach and create a binary expansion of each integer, i.e, $v_1 = b_{01} + 2b_{11}+4b_{21}...$. With that, we can exploit the fact that a product of expressions involving binaries, can be linearized by introducing a large amount of new variables and constraints (that is why I limit this to $N=4$). Hence, a MILP is obtained again. This linearization is available in YALMIP in the command `binmodel`. The code runs for a while and then terminates with a counter example, typically for $P=2$

```
ok = 1
while ok
    % Random data for small instance
    N = 4;
    P = ceil(rand(1)*N^2);
    alpha = ceil(rand(1,N)*sqrt(N));

    % Create a binary expansion
    d = 1+floor(log2(N));
    b = binvar(d,N,'full');
    v = (2.^(0:1:d-1))*b;

    % Solve by by binary linearization. Expensive!
    Model = [sum(v)==P, v <= N];
    [Objective,cut] = binmodel(prod((alpha.^2+v)));
    solvesdp([cut,Model],-Objective);
    trueobj = double(Objective);
    v1 = double(v);

    % Solve by integer model and simple objective
    v = intvar(1,N);
    sdpvar smallest largest
    Model = [sum(v)==P,0 <= v <= N, smallest <= alpha.^2+v <= largest]
    solvesdp(Model, largest-smallest)      
    objalternative = prod(alpha.^2+double(v));
    v2 = double(v)

    % Check for failure
    ok = abs(trueobj-objalternative)<=1e-8
    if ~ok                
        trueobj
        v1
        v1+alpha.^2
        objalternative
        v2
        v2+alpha.^2 
        break
    end     
end
```

Hopefully I've missed something simple, as the MILP model with deviation of $v_i+\alpha_i^2$ is really fast and terminates in 0s for $N=200$. The known correct method with the binary expansion is intractable for $N>5$ or something like that. Obviously, a problem is that the distance measure leads to non-unique solutions here

Here is one of the problematic cases

```
P =

     2


alpha^2 =

     1     1     1     4

trueobj =

    16


v1 =

     0     1     1     0


v1+alpha^2 =

     1     2     2     4


objalternative =

    12


v2 =

     2     0     0     0


v2+alpha^2 =

     3     1     1     4
```

Answer (score -1):

With the lagrange multipliers, I get :

$\forall i \ \ v_i=\frac{(P+\sum\alpha_i^2)}{N}- \alpha_i^2$.

What do you think ?

Comment: This is correct for the continuous case but these $v_i$ are not necessarily integers.

Comment: Have you made some tests to determine if this was ok to use the floor or ceiling functions ?

Comment: As I have mentioned in my post, rounding might not be optimal. By my approach, floor and ceiling will do even worse.

Comment: Are your alpha integers as well?

Comment: You haven't answered my last question. If they are integers then floor and ceiling functions should be ok

Comment: Whoops, sorry! No the alpha arent integers

Comment: How do you mean you have used Lagrange multipliers? This is the unconstrained solution (i.e., you have not only relaxed the integrality, but you have removed the upper and lower bounds). The solutions are often completely off as some elements will be significanly negative